# Does Judaism say that souls can or cannot be destroyed?

Tags: soul

Does Judaism say that souls can or cannot be destroyed? Just asking because I was raised a Christian, and it didn't make any sense to me, at all, that a "soul" could be destroyed. All I know is that's an important part of [Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Way).

Comment: Why would a soul be any different than any other creation, which presumably can be destroyed just like it was created?

Comment: Define what you mean by a soul being "destroyed." Do you mean that the soul ceases to exist or that it is punished eternally in Gehenna?